# Structure variable has Pointer variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure

I want to know why structure variable passes pointer variable to create memory.

1. what happens if we do `box *boxes = malloc(n * sizeof(box));`
2. Then we pass address to `scanf` function. Pointer actually stores the address. Then why we pass "&" of scanf to pointer ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d%d%d", &boxes[i].length, &boxes[i].width, &boxes[i].height);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_HEIGHT 41

struct box
{
    /**
    * Define three fields of type int: length, width and height
    */
    int length,width,height;
};

typedef struct box box;

int get_volume(box b) {
    /**
    * Return the volume of the box
    */
    return b.length*b.width*b.height;
}

int is_lower_than_max_height(box b) {
    /**
    * Return 1 if the box's height is lower than MAX_HEIGHT and 0 otherwise
    */
    return b.height < 41 ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    box *boxes = malloc(n * sizeof(box));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &boxes[i].length, &boxes[i].width, &boxes[i].height);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (is_lower_than_max_height(boxes[i])) {
            printf("%d\n", get_volume(boxes[i]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- When I tried running the sizeof struct,I got the sizeof Struct box it was 12.
- Say n = 5, Then what will be the memory space?
  memory = 12 * 5 ?

Comment: Just like in a Book-Library you need Room, Section, Row, Column etc details to place a book, `scanf()` needs exact location where it can store a value. Book-Library is like base address of the structure here.

Answer (score 2):

1. `malloc()` is used to allocate dynamic and variable sized memory. So we use this to create an array of `n` structures.
2. You need `&` because `scanf()` needs the address of the variable to store the input data to. `b` is a pointer, but `b[i].length` is just an ordinary structure member accessed by dereferencing that pointer. You need to get its address to pass to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 box *boxes = malloc(n * sizeof(box));
```

Allocates enough space for n instances of box on the heap and returns a pointer to it

```
 scanf("%d%d%d", &boxes[i].length///
```

is passing the address of `boxes[i].length` to scanf. Scanf needs to write there so its needs the address. Its just like

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

that you did earlier

```
 sizeof(struct box)
```

equaling 12 is fine. It has 3, 4 byte integers. You wont always get it that simply , the compiler might pad the structure to align things on 2, 4 or 8 byte boundaries, this is why `sizeof` exists

> Say n = 5, Then what will be the memory space? memory = 12 * 5 ?

yes